# how to show the remaining percent of Bar in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, css, html, highcharts

I want to show the remaining percent of bar in grey color like this in image[image]

so far i have tried this and unable to find this type in Highcharts documentation
so please tell me how should i solve this with highcharts documentation or jquery

```
Highcharts.chart('Chart1Progress', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: null
    },
    title: null,
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        visible: false,
        shadow: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: null,
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
            }
        },

    },
    legend: {
       enabled: false,
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'black',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{ y: 5, color: 'red' }, { y: 3, color: '#DDDF0D' }, { y: 4, color: '#55BF3B' }, { y: 7, color: '#5dacdf' }, { y: 2, color: 'pink' }]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/at8m1r24/

Comment: I'm not sure you can with the api. But you can "draw" the lines with css (creating `div` below the chart). Or you can use javascript to add SVG lines to the SVG that highchart created.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to add a second series that you calculate as the delta of your existing series point and your max, and set the color of that series to the grey that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Highcharts.chart('Chart1Progress',{
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            backgroundColor: null,
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        visible: false,
        },
        yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: null,
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
            }
        },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            },
            bar: {
                grouping: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -30,
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'black',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: true
        },
        series: [ {
            name: 'Remaining',
            data: [3, 5, 4, 1, 6],
            borderWidth: 0,
            color: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        },{
            name: 'Remaining',
            data: [3, 5, 4, 1, 6],
            borderWidth: 0,
            stack: 1,
            animation: false,
            color: "gray"
        }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [{ y: 5, color: 'red' }, { y: 3, color: '#DDDF0D' }, { y: 4, color: '#55BF3B' }, { y: 7, color: '#5dacdf' }, { y: 2, color: 'pink' }]
    }]
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="Chart1Progress" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

You should set the stacking to percent and few data to stack